# optimize the query with multiple table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the query in which data are coming from multiple tables.

```
SELECT iUserID,
       iUserID AS userID,
       (CASE vUSBG
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes'
            WHEN 0 THEN 'No'
        END) AS vUSBG,
       concat(vFirstname,' ',vLastname) AS Name,
       vEmail,
       eType,
       eStatus,
       tAddedDate,
       eExpert,
       eAdmin,

  (SELECT count(iUserID) AS total
   FROM tbl_friend
   WHERE iUserID = tbl_user.iUserID) AS count_f,

  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM bar_followers
   WHERE bar_followers.iUserID = tbl_user.iUserID) AS bar_follows,

  (SELECT COUNT(b.iBrandID)
   FROM tbl_company_follow,
        tbl_brand b
   WHERE tbl_company_follow.iUserID = tbl_user.iUserID
     AND b.iCompanyID = tbl_company_follow.iCompanyID) AS brand_follows,

  (SELECT sum(points) AS totalpoints
   FROM tbl_points,
        tbl_post p
   WHERE iUserID = tbl_user.iUserID
     AND p.iPostID = tbl_points.post_id) AS countPoints
FROM tbl_user
```

*This Query took `8.3595 seconds`*

How can i minimize the time?

Comment: http://sqlformat.org/ is your friend :)

Comment: but how can i manage it in this large query?

Comment: but it is taking `8.3595 sec`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is reasonable, except for the lack of explicit `join` syntax.

Check to be sure that you have the following indexes:

- `tbl_friend(iUserId)`
- `bar_followers(iUserID)`
- `tbl_company_follow(iUserID, iCompanyID)`
- `tbl_brand(iCompanyID)`
- `tbl_post(iUserID, iPostID)`
- `tbl_points(post_id, points)`

However, depending on the size of your data, 8-9 seconds might be reasonable.

Comment: there are only 750 records and it is taking this much of time

Comment: @bluto . . . 99.7% improvement.  Not bad ;)

Comment: yes.. and that is good for now.. i'll try to do it using `join`

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to judge whether a sub ten second query time is reasonable without knowing your table sizes.  It may near to the best you can do.

That being said, you can refactor this query to use LEFT JOIN operations in place of your dependent subqueries.   That will go something like this outline.

```
SELECT tu.field, tu.field, ...
       a.count_f,
       b.bar_follows,
       ...
  FROM tbl_user tu
  LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT count(*) AS count_f, iUserID
                FROM tbl_friend
               GROUP BY iUserID
       ) a ON tu.iUserID = a.iUserId
  LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT count(*) AS bar_follows, iUserID
               FROM bar_followers
              GROUP BY iUserId
       ) b ON tu.iUserID = b.iUserId
 ...
```

There are two related things going on here. First every `COUNT()` item is `COUNT(*)`. That allows the query to be satisfied without looking at the contents of each row.

Second, the dependent subqueries in your column list are replaced with subqueries working out the aggregate data you need. This may help, because the query planner can perform each subquery just once.

Gordon's right about the indexes.